# Magento2 Indexer ATTRIBUTES_CHUNK_SIZE

Tags: magento2, indexer, magento-core

In ***Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Action\Indexer*** there is one constant:

```
/**
 * Maximum size of attributes chunk
 */
const ATTRIBUTES_CHUNK_SIZE = 59;
```

reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Flat/Action/Indexer.php#L26

It serves for splitting attributes into chunks during Flat table indexation process.

The question is: **Why 59?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql has a limit of 63 joins per query. The 4 remaining are reserved for things like website and category associations.

Comment: Great answer, wasn't thought about that limitation in the variety of MySQL limitations.